# Display mysql datetime in human readable format with php?

Tags: php, mysql

Am saving to a mysql table using:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test SET postit='$postit',postdate=NOW()");
```

I'm then trying to display it using:

```
echo "<li>" . date("D, d M y H:i:s O",$row['timestamp']) . " - " . $row['postit'] . "</li>";
```

It's saving the correct time in the database, however it renders:

> Thu, 01 Jan 70 01:00:00 +0100

Anyone point out the stupidity?

Comment: What does `$row['timestamp']` output?

Comment: the value of now() from the database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PHP date() function uses a Unix timestamp as the second variable in the function.  What you are passing to the function is a MySQL time stamp.  Try using:

```
echo date("D, d M y H:i:s O",strtotime($row['timestamp']));
```

Comment: Yes, `NOW()` in mysql is an actual date, not a timestamp. Good eye.

Answer (score 2):

I always like to use this function for that:

```
function parse_sql_timestamp($timestamp, $format = 'd-m-Y')
{
    $date = new DateTime($timestamp);
    return $date->format($format);
}
```

This way we can even go beyond 2038 ;)